# Object reference error while dealing with datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to insert a blank new row in DataGrid in Silverlight when I press Inser key. But, while doing this it gives me an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I am using a table and a Observeable Collection named Bounddata.

I am checking the index of the row I have clicked, and then I want to insert a new blank row where user can enter the information. And the new data is stored back into the database.

I have written the code below:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Insert)        
{                
    ATClientDependent r = new ATClientDependent() { DependentGUID = Guid.NewGuid() };
    int index = BoundData.IndexOf(dataGrid.SelectedItem as ATClientDependent);
    BoundData.Insert(index, r);
    dataGrid.SelectedIndex = index;
    dataGrid.BeginEdit();
    proxy.AddObject("ATClientDependents", r);
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code in the debugger to identify a `null` object whose property you might be accessing or method you're calling.

Based on the code you've posted it could be `e`, `BoundData`, `dataGrid`, `proxy` or anything in the method `proxy.AddObject`.

You should also look at the stack trace of the error - it'll give you the line number where the exception occurs.